# Get image Url to show one a single image name

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrape, imageurl

have an issue with this. I am not sure how to go about showing a single img. For example:

```
<img srcset="http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTERNATES/s180/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg 180w, http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTERNATES/s390/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg 390w, http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTERNATES/s458/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg 458w" src="http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg">
```

As you can see above, there are different alternative images, however i am trying to scrape a single one to be shown.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import datetime
import random 
import re


random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

# 




title = soup.title
link = soup.link
image = re.search(img 'srcset=img(.*?),)  
 #this doesnt work, not sure how to 

strong = soup.strong
description = soup.description
location = soup.location


title = soup.find('h1', class_ ='publication-font', )   

image = soup.find('img')
strong = soup.find('strong')
location = soup.find('em').find('a')
description = soup.find('div', class_='description',to.text)


#Previous Code
print("H1:", title.text)
print("Article Link:", link)
print("Image Url:\n", image)
print("1st Paragraph:\n", strong.text)
print("2nd Paragraph:\n", description.string)
print("Location:\n", location.text)
```

My code is above, however the previous result when on my previous try would show:

```
Greater Manchester News
<link href="rss.xml" rel="alternate" title="Default home feed" 

type="application/rss+xml"/>

<img data-`src="http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTERNA`TES/s615/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg" data-`srcset="http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTE`RNATES/s180/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg 180w,` http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALT`ERNATES/s

390/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-the-attack-outside-his-`Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg 390w, `http://i4.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/incoming/article13390833.ece/ALTERNATES/s458/Mike-Grimshaw-34-was-fatally-attacked-following-t`he-attack-outs`ide-his-

Trafford-home-last-Thursday.jpg 458w"/>
        Family of dad stabbed in the neck while defendin

g his fiancée from thugs speak of their heartbreak
        Mike Grimshaw, 34, died after being stabbed in the neck outside his 

home in Trafford last Thursday

Trafford
```

In the results, shows multiple image names, however i am trying to only show a single image link. How do i go about doing this.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attribute `data-src` or `data-srcset` to get the image you want :

```
image = soup.find('img')
single_img = image.get('data-src') # return the main image link
```

or

```
import re
image = soup.find('img')
img_string = image.get('data-srcset') # this return a string you have to parse 
img_set = re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', img_set) # regex to match only links
```

Then you can access whatever index you want in img_set (just test the length of the list before)